# Вопрос по поводу вёрстки в Android Studio из Figma

Tags: android, android-layout, design, android-xml, figma

Всем привет! Подскажите, как быть в ситуации: есть дизайн в Figma. В нём есть две кнопки на одной горизонтали. Размеры каждой кнопки в дизайне 125х44 пикселя. Также по бокам у них отступ 35пикселей и между ними 40 пикселей.
Вопрос - как мне это сверстать в Android Studio? Надо ли мне делать horizontal chain и указывать размеры как match constraints у ширины этих кнопок?
Или просто указать размеры кажой 125dp на 44dp и отсутпы тоже по 35dp и всё?

Comment: не задавайте жестко размер элементов верстки, только отступы. У всех устройств размеры и разрешения экранов разные, с жестко заданными размерами элементов - вся верстка поедет. Для проверки - можно запустить два эмулятора (с маленьким и с большим размером экрана). Кроме того, советую использовать вот [эту](https://github.com/intuit/sdp) библиотеку для отступов.

Comment: Ого, спасибо, первый раз вижу такую библиотеку, хотя у неё аж 1.5к звёзд
Но ни разу не видел чтобы про неё где-то говорили